# Sharing links with request uri consist of "&a=xyz&b=mnp" on WhatsApp using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, whatsapp, urlencode

After sharing the URL in whatsapp, it was trimmed to path. It picks the URL up to first occurance of "&".

```
https://api.whatsapp.com/.....?text=http://xyzdomain.com?&a=xyz&b=mnp
```

I was expecting the url to be shared in chat something like (http://xyzdomain.com?&a=xyz&b=mnp) but it is `http://xyzdomain.com?`

Comment: can we see your php code ?

Comment: Formatted the question to make it more readable.  Enclose the code or HTML inside quotes to show it show

Answer (score 0):

you should learn how to concat between text and php

if you have variable var and equal to Abanoub

```
$var = "Abanoub";
```

and you want to echo hello $var you should do it as:

```
echo "Hello " . $var;
```

we use "." to concat between text and php var so you should write

```
<?php echo "http://example.com/?s=".$sender."&r=".$receiver."&d=".$d."&m=".$m; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found. We can use the encoded URL in the WhatsApp link instead of decoded URL.
I think used URL encoder in PHP.